# Arduino, understanding invalid conversion warning, unsigned char to char*

Tags: c++, arduino, type-conversion, warnings, platformio

Edit:

Resolved, can't accept my answer for two days

---

I'm using PlatformIO to program a Arduino Nano to write a message to an OLED display.

I'm calling a function `printWeight`:

```
void printWeight(
        float weight,
        uint8_t scale=3,
        uint8_t numbd=3,
        uint8_t numad=2,
        bool kg=false,
        const char* description_text_line="Weight:",
        uint8_t width_per_character=5+1,
        uint8_t height_per_line=7+3
        ){
    ...
```

The function is centering the text by calculating the leading space `leading_space` and calls itself with a smaller scale (`scale-1`) if the message doesn't fit on the screen:

```
if(leading_space < 0){
        printWeight(weight, scale-1, numbd, numad, description_text_line,
                width_per_character, height_per_line);
        return;
    }
```

The code compiles and runs fine. However I'm getting the following warning that I don't know how to resolve:

```
src/main.cpp: In function 'void printWeight(float, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, bool, const char*, uint8_t, uint8_t)':
src/main.cpp:138:53: warning: invalid conversion from 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
                 width_per_character, height_per_line);
                                                     ^
src/main.cpp:93:6: note:   initializing argument 6 of 'void printWeight(float, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, bool, const char*, uint8_t, uint8_t)'
 void printWeight(
      ^
```

How do I get rid of this warning?

Comment: When you pass `width_per_character` to `const char*` it causes the warning because the variable is a `uint8_t`.

Comment: It seems you forgot to write an argument for `kg`.

Comment: You forgot the `kg` argument, so all arguments shifted by one place.

Comment: Your `description_text_line` argument can be converted to `bool`, so that is accepted as the `kg` argument. If the code runs fine now, it's most likely because you never use the `description_text_line` parameter.

Comment: Stupid mistake, sorry. All parameters are being used and work as expected, which is why I didn't search for a missing parameter. Any idea why all parameters are accessible correctly? The display is showing `Weight:` in the normal and the rescaled version with `display.write(description_text_line);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing parameter...
Thanks to the ones commenting.